# Does 筈はなくて grammar construction have a negative connotation?

Tags: grammar, translation

I found the construction 筈はなくて and by helping me with the context, I suppose to have properly translated but I am not sure.

> このバックパックは特殊な製法でできていて、見た目の大きさよりずっと多くのアイテムが収納できる魔法の袋…とまぁ、そんな都合のいいものの筈はなくて、
>   This backpack has been done in a special way, it is a magical bag that you can put many more items than what appears to be possible to put in it ... but it does not turn to my advantage!
>
> 生地の限界がくれば溢れるし破れる。
>   If it is filled beyond its limits, things come out and break.
>
> 勿論重さも健在だ。
>   Of course, the important thing is that I am alive and well.
>
> 夢のような便利なアイテムはないんだよね。
>   Yeah, is not an object of your dreams, it is not easy to handle!

Is it correct my interpretation of そんな都合のいいものの筈はなくて?

I think that the subject is denying the fact that the backpack is convenient.

Comment: 重さも健在 is a half-joking phrase which I don't know how to translate naturally, but it's "Its weight is also there" (ie, there's no way the content of the bag can be weightless, either.) And you may have gotten the last sentence wrong. Double-check whether it was 便利なアイテム**で**はない or 便利なアイテムはない.

Comment: Hello  Naruto,

the last sentence is 夢のような便利なアイテムはないんだよね。
this is my translation: Yeah , is not an object so dreamy and handy! 

I guess it does make sense if it is linked to the previous sentence 生地の限界がくれば溢れるし破れる。
If it is filled beyond its limits, things come out and break.

As for 重さも健在 the sense could be "Of course the weight (the items contained in the backpack) must be safe and sound!
Are you agree?
Thanks,
Nadia

Comment: Note that で changes the meaning of the sentence critically. 本ではない means "This is not a book" and 本はない means "There is no book."

Comment: The subject of 破れる is the bag, not "things". 夢のような便利なアイテムはないんだよね。means 夢のような便利なアイテムなど存在しない, a perfect item of your dreams cannot ever exist.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is the idea that the backpack is unusual, nearly magical, in how much it can contain despite its apparent small size.  The finishing phrase:

> そんな都合のいいものの筈はなくて

筈{はず} in this context refers to the speaker's *expectation*.  The なくて here is a conjugation of ない *"not"*, so yes, this has a negative connotation.  Much as in English advertisements, this full phrase could be translated as *"there's **no way** this could be so good!"*

Another more prosaic example of 筈 usage (usually written in kana) in a positive context might be あの手紙はもう届いた**はず**だ。 → *"The **expectation** is that that letter has already been delivered."* (literally) → *"I'm **pretty sure** that letter has been delivered by now."* (more idiomatically)

Comment: Thank you a lot! There is a negative connotation because the speaker couldn't t think that it could be so helpful! So it is to translate: "a thing like this so useful? Impossible to immagine!
Right?

Thanks,
Nadia

Comment: @Nadia From what I've seen, 都合のいい often tends to be a pretty negative expression too - I've always read 都合のいい人 to be 勝手なことをする人, for example. It's obviously not quite the same context here, but I think it does add to the negativity even here.